# Two dropdown filters. The first determines the info in the second

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, underscore.js

I'm not sure how to build this although I've spent several hours trying. My code seems somewhat close but I'm unable to pass my selection from the HTML back to the controller.

My Angular code:

```
 var Categories = Parse.Object.extend("bizCategories");

        $scope.categories = [
            {category: "Food and Drink"},
            {category: "Healthcare"},
            {category: "Recreation"},
            {category: "Service"},
            {category: "Shops"},
            {category: "Travel"}
        ]

        $scope.setPrimary = function (category) {
            $scope.offer.primary = category;
            $scope.secondaryCategories(category);
        };

        $scope.secondaryCategories = function(category){
            var Secondary = new Parse.Query(Categories);
            Secondary.limit(1000);
            Secondary.find({
                success:function(list){
                    $scope.SecondaryCategories = _.uniq(_.filter(_.map(list, function(item){
                        return{primary: item.get('secondary')
                        }}
                    )),'primary',true)
                    console.log($scope.SecondaryCategories);
                },
                error: function(error){alert("A mistake was made.");
                }
            })
        }
```

My html:

```
  <select id= 'primary' ng-model="offer.primary" ng-options="XXX.category for XXX in categories"
                ng-click= setPrimary(category)>
            <option value="">Primary Business Category</option>
        </select>

        <select id= 'secondary' ng-model="offer.secondary" ng-disabled="!offer.primary"
                ng-options="XXX.category for XXX in SecondaryCategories" ng-click="setSecondary('XXX.category')">
            <option value="">Secondary Business Category</option>
        </select>
```

You'll see that I picked XXX in my html for ng-options. I picked that because from what I can tell from the tutorials, the purpose to call it anything in particular is arbitrary and I made this XXX as a not on that matter. Also, I need info from the first dropdown to carry over to the function for the second dropdown (category) but that is showing up as undefined.

The data source:

[image: Primary is the first selection criteria and exists as array in the first controller. Secondary is filtered using primary; it's a many to many relationship.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to set the other dropdown on selection of 1. You should use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)  instead of `ng-click`.

Try:-

```
    <select id= 'primary' ng-model="offer.primary" ng-options="XXX.category for XXX in categories"
            ng-change= setPrimary(category)>
        <option value="">Primary Business Category</option>
    </select>

    <select id= 'secondary' ng-model="offer.secondary" ng-disabled="!offer.primary"
            ng-options="XXX.category for XXX in SecondaryCategories" ng-change="setSecondary('XXX.category')">
        <option value="">Secondary Business Category</option>
    </select>
```

Since your `ng-model` is already bound to `offer.primary` , you can avoid doing `$scope.offer.primary = category;`  since the  ng-model would have been set already.

Comment: Thanks, ng-change was very useful for passing the selected value from the drop down to the model. Any guidance on fixing the secondaryCategories function so it does the second round of filtering on the second dropdown?

Comment: @rashadb You have not mentioned that in your question. What is the issue with that, and what are you doing there? Did this answer your original question?

Comment: PSL - thanks for getting back with me. It answered part of it. I now know that whatever I choose goes into the set primary function. However I can't get that info to the secondaryCategories function which is the main thing I'm trying to to do. I posted a follow up on this last night.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979200/i-cant-render-my-second-and-dependent-dropdown
The issue is getting that selection in the first drop down, offer.primary to fall programmatically in place of what is hardcoded as 'Travel' in the secondaryCategories function.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Do you have a demo to showcase the issue., if not please let me know i am going to remove my answer.

Comment: oh well you have a typo `setSecondary` vs `setSecondaryCategories`

Comment: Your answer is helpful you should leave it. I will attempt to set up a demo this afternoon. And there is no typo - setSecondary is the response from the second dropdown and SecondaryCategories is the processed input from setPrimary that filters the second drop down.

Comment: The issue I'm having is with offer.primary (html)/$scope.offer.primary. I use console.log($scope.offer.primary); to see that it makes it into the setPrimary function.  Once it is there I need to move that value to the $scope.SecondaryCategory function as a programmatic filter.  My latest effort

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979200/i-cant-render-my-second-and-dependent-dropdown

I added a Secondary.equalTo('primary', 'Travel'); query to the function where 'Travel' is a hard coded choice for $scope.offer.primary. The function returns the correct array of values with that info.

Comment: That is what you are passing right by doing `$scope.secondaryCategories(category);` does it not work? I think a demo would help understand the issue better.. :(

Comment: I've been fooling around with JS Fiddle but I can't get it to run the code :( 
I just managed to confirm that the value selected for $scope.offer.primary carries into $scope.secondaryCategories function above.  Still the function returns an empty array with $scope.offer.primary but it turns the correct array when I type in a hard coded answer from the $scope.categories array above like "Food and Drink". 

I'll keep fiddling with JS fiddle to see if I can get it working unless there is a better demo site you know of.

Comment: Use plunker instead of jsfiddle.

Comment: PSL, thanks for your help. I figured out the next step and that was taking the value out of my object in the $scope.secondaryCategories portion of the code.

I couldn't have done it without your help though!